# Mutate new columns and intercalate them with old ones

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to create new columns using `across` and that new columns being intercalated with the old ones. In the example I manually relocate the columns to show the desired output. But I would like to do this automatically, like my try inside `mutate`, which obviously does not work.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = 1:2, x_b = 1:2, x_c = 1:2)

df |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("x_"), 
                ~ .x * 2, 
                .names = "{sub('x_', 'y_', .col)}"),
         .after = c(x_b, x_c)) |> 
  relocate(y_b, .after = x_b) |> 
  relocate(y_c, .after = x_c)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>       a   x_b   y_b   x_c   y_c
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     2     1     2
#> 2     2     2     4     2     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What you are looking for in across unfortunately isn‘t possible: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6223

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could create a tibble/data.frame, use `.unpack` option and rename the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("x_"), 
                ~ data.frame(x = .x, y = .x * 2), .unpack = TRUE),
   .keep = 'unused') %>% 
 rename_with(~ str_replace(.x, "x_(.)_(.)", "\\2_\\1"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
      a   x_b   y_b   x_c   y_c
  <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     1     2
2     2     2     4     2     4
```

Answer (score 3):

A dirty workaround that I‘m using regularly:

```
library(tidyverse)

prefix <- c('x_', 'y_')
suffix <- c('b', 'c')

col_order <- paste0(prefix, rep(suffix, each = length(prefix)))

df %>%
  select(a, all_of(col_order))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
      a   x_b   y_b   x_c   y_c
  <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     1     2
2     2     2     4     2     4
```

Comment: This works for the reprex, but it's tedious in my real case where the dataset has 50 columns and I need to mutate about 10 that are in the middle. However, this is a smart workaround.

Comment: If you‘d provide a more complete reprex (with like 20 cols in their natural order), we could see what we can do. Even with 50 cols, there might be a way. E.g. in the select command it could look like`select(a:k, all_of(col_order), everything())`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried to do the reprex as simple as possible, but probably too much.